# adding .dll external file reference to my project doesn't work

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to add an External Reference to my Windows Forms project. I have the file named "ExtendedRichTextBox.dll" externaly from another project I downloaded from CodeProject.com

I added it, by browsing for it from Add reference dialog, and did also another time by copying the file to the debug folder of my project and adding the reference then from extensions.

Either way, the reference's proper function is not working. (I added "using ExtendedRichTextBox" to directive usings)

help !

Comment: after added the reference, can you see it under "all references" in your project ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thank you.
I managed to handle the problem it was on because the richtextbox I'm using was declared as this.richTextBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.richtextbox where it should be declared as an extendedrichtextbox extention:
What should've been done was declaring "this.richTextBox1 = new ExtendedRichTextBox.RichTextBoxPrintCtrl();"